# Theme select field with ul li in register form

Tags: entities, theming, users

I have a field in account settings named 'field_country' which is a select list.

I have defined it as an ajax field in template.php

```
$form['field_country'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $countries,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'change_country',
    'wrapper' => 'city',
  ),
);
```

Then when you change the value it calls correctly 'change_country' with ajax and works perfectly.

My problem is that I want is to change this select/option input by an ul/li list, and call ajax method like its original version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try using a widget that looks and acts like a select list, but is made HTML list & Javascript.